# UDP stops sending after first time

Tags: c++, sockets, networking, udp

I'm using a UDP socket to transmit data from a C++ client to a c# server .
But, after first transfer from client the UDP client socket was to stop operate!

Just only client socket stops, server send data normaly.

I don't see a problem.

client c++ :

```
unsigned char IPv4[4];
if (getMyIp(IPv4))
{
    char strIP[256];
    sprintf(strIP,"%i.%i.%i.%i", (int) IPv4[0], (int) IPv4[1], (int) IPv4[2], (int) IPv4[3] );
    strcpy( Configurator::LOCAL_IP, strIP );
    //std::cout<<"IP: "<<strIP<<"\n";

    // Open windows connection
    conectado = false;

    if(WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2),&WsaDat)!=0)
    {
        messagelog("Winsock error - Winsock initialization failed");
        WSACleanup();
        return 0;
    }

    //Open a datagram socket
    Socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
    if (Socket == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        messagelog("Could not create socket.\n");
        WSACleanup();
        return 0;
    }

    //options

    #ifndef IP_MULTICAST_TTL
        #define IP_MULTICAST_TTL 3
    #endif
    #ifndef IP_MULTICAST_LOOP
        #define IP_MULTICAST_LOOP 4
    #endif
    unsigned char one = 1;
    unsigned char ttl = 3;
    setsockopt(Socket, IPPROTO_IP, IP_MULTICAST_TTL, (const char*) &ttl,
          sizeof(unsigned char));
    setsockopt(Socket, IPPROTO_IP, IP_MULTICAST_LOOP,
                   (const char*) &one, sizeof(unsigned char));

    // Clear out server struct
    memset((void *)&SockAddr, '\0', sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));

    // Set family and port
    SockAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    SockAddr.sin_port = htons( Configurator::PORT ); //porta
    SockAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr( Configurator::IP /*strIP*/ ); // ip local

    // Clear out client struct
    memset((void *)&SockAddrClient, '\0', sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));
    // Set family and port
    SockAddrClient.sin_family = AF_INET;
    SockAddrClient.sin_port = htons(0);
    SockAddrClient.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr( strIP ); // ip local // htonl(INADDR_ANY);

    if (bind(Socket, (struct sockaddr *)&SockAddrClient, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in)) == -1)
    {
        messagelog("Cannot bind address to socket.");
        WSACleanup();
        return 0;
    }
    server_length = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
```

send code

```
  int ok = sendto(Socket, mensagem, (int)strlen(mensagem) + 1, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&SockAddr, server_length);
    std::cout<<ok<<"\n";
```

ok is aways -1 after first send!

server C#:

```
System.Net.IPEndPoint ip = new System.Net.IPEndPoint( System.Net.IPAddress.Any, PORT);
        conn = new System.Net.Sockets.Socket(
            System.Net.Sockets.AddressFamily.InterNetwork, System.Net.Sockets.SocketType.Dgram, System.Net.Sockets.ProtocolType.Udp);
        conn.MulticastLoopback = true;

        conn.Bind(ip);

        sender = new System.Net.IPEndPoint(System.Net.IPAddress.Any,0);
        remote = (System.Net.EndPoint)(sender);
        System.Console.WriteLine("udp " + PORT);
```

to receive:

```
int res = conn.ReceiveFrom(b, ref Connector.instance.remote);
```

Comment: sorry Bitetti, I don't think anyone can understand your question.

Comment: I don't see that you are doing any send calls at all in your client.

Comment: And what is this Configurator thingy?

Comment: Get configuration data from arquive

Comment: Can you call WSAGetLastError to get more information about error after your sendto function fails? What Wireshark is catching? Are your trying to send to multicast group or this is normal unicast connection? If it is multicast then you need to join to multicast group using setsockopt and IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP. Without this you want be able to receive anything from group.

Comment: And what is the value of errno after you get the -1?

Comment: Hi! tanks for help. My error number is 10058. I'm still working on it

Comment: This error message means either you have shut down the socket after the first transmission, or the size of the buffer you are sending is larger than that which (in your case) server can receive. Or if the received had a "disk-full" condition, or something similar. Ref: http://support.ipswitch.com/kb/WSK-19980714-EM29.htm

Btw, why do you do this: "(int)strlen(mensagem) + 1" in the sendto()?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all comments!
Without you I would not have solved.

the error is here

```
//recebe via UDP
inDataLength = recvfrom( Socket, recBuf, BUFFDERECEBIMENTO_SIZE, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&SockAddrClient, &server_length);
```

The main loop of data receivement.
After add a error message to the process. I restrict the error to length of the buffer (recBuf) .
After pass from 512bytes to 65546bytes the crash is ending.